# A sentence consisting of two negative parts

Tags: negation, complex-sentences

I'm editing a text (in En) by somebody else and he uses a language construction that is not uncommon in our language. Now I'm a bit confused:

> If these two processes did not happen simultaneously, we could not
>   observe the spectrum part.

1) is this sentence at all normal and understandable?
2) should we avoid this negative structure? I proposed to change the sentence to:

> Just because these two processes happen simultaneously, we can
>   observe...

But maybe the original sentence is not so bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proposed change makes a slight difference to the meaning. The original is fine; this structure is common is scientific writing. "Spectrum part" is a bit odd though.

Your "just because" is problematic because it's common in a construction like "just because you're bigger than me doesn't mean you can eat all the cake". If you really needed to avoid the negative construction, you'd be better off starting "It is only because", but you don't need to.

Comment: Thank you very much Chris, and thank God you could answer my question before some native speakers who never understand what problems have a non-native speaker blocked it. Unfortunately, it means also, as I understand it now, that you receive no points.

Comment: I do appear to have got the points, but I'm not too worried about that anyway. I can be quite willing to close vote myself, but couldn't think where you could look this up